# How do I send multiple array requests?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Sorry if my question seems vague, but I need to know how to do the following. I have this method that sends a arrays to a server like so.

ViewController.m

```
[requestHandler getRequest:array_id[0]];
```

RequestHandler.m

```
-(void)getRequest:(NSMutableArray)array {
   __weak ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request addPostValue:array forKey:@"array_id[0]"];
}
```

As you can see I can send the first value of the array perfectly.However, I need to send the arrays like so array_id[0], array_id [1], array_id [3], array_id [4] to the server through addPostValue.The array count is always different. So I need to do something like the following. Pretty much keep adding on to request method and post method based on array count.

```
-(void)getRequest:(NSMutableArray)array array1:(NSMutableArray *)array1 {
    [request addPostValue:array forKey:@"array_id[0]"];
    [request addPostValue:array1 forKey:@"array_id[1]"];
}
```

What is the best way to perform such a task and keep in mind that the array count is always different so I need a way to keep adding to both the getrequest method and request addpost method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could just have one `getRequest` method that receives an `NSArray` containing *x* number of arrays. Something like:

```
- (void)getRequest:(NSArray*)array {
    for (uint i = 0; i<array.count; i++) {
        NSArray *arr = array[i];
        [request addPostValue:arr forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"array_id[%i]", i]];
    }
}
```

Then, call like so:

```
[requestHandler getRequest:@[array_id[0], array_id[1]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

What will be more easy is, that you make a JSON/XML of your arrays and then pass that to your request builder.

It is not at all a good approach to implement such logics while building requests and calling servers.

Better approach for this is to make a json of an array and then post it to the server, server then can decode the json and use it in whatsoever form it wants to use.

This will be a more simple and structured approach.